# Uncaught TypeError: Providing your root Epic to createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Providing your root Epic to
>   `createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)` is no longer supported, instead use
>   `epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic)`

When simply using

```
import 'rxjs'
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'

import app from './app'

// Bundling Epics
const rootEpic = combineEpics(
)

// Creating Bundled Epic
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)

// Define Middleware
const middleware = [
  thunk,
  promise(),
  epicMiddleware
]

// Define Reducers
const reducers = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer
})

// Create Store
export default createStore(reducers,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(), applyMiddleware(...middleware))
```

Kindly help to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import 'rxjs'
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'

import app from './app'

// Bundling Epics
const rootEpic = combineEpics(
)

// Creating Bundled Epic
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

// Define Middleware
const middleware = [
  thunk,
  promise(),
  epicMiddleware
]

// Define Reducers
const reducers = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer
})

// Create Store
const store = createStore(reducers,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(), applyMiddleware(...middleware))
epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
export default store
```

official documentation [createEpicMiddleware](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/api/createEpicMiddleware.html).

Comment: @DarkKnight I added the official documentation for more info.

Comment: I am getting warning `redux-observable | WARNING: epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic) called before the middleware has been setup by redux. Provide the epicMiddleware instance to createStore() first.`

Comment: @DarkKnight like in the documentation it seems that the store must be created before doing `epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);`

Answer (score 2):

First, take a look at this document: [Official Redux-Observable Document](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/api/createEpicMiddleware.html) because we're using the newest version of Redux-Observable, then reviewing its document is quite helpful.

After reviewing the document, let's see a small example project (Counter app):

This is the `root.js` file which contains my Epics and Reducers after bundling.

```
// This is a sample reducers and epics for a Counter app.
import { combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';


import counter, {
  setCounterEpic,
  incrementEpic,
  decrementEpic
} from './reducers/counter';

// bundling Epics
export const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  setCounterEpic,
  incrementEpic,
  decrementEpic
);

// bundling Reducers
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  counter
});
```

And this is `store.js` where I define my store before using it.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import { rootEpic, rootReducer } from './root';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

const middlewares = [
  epicMiddleware
]

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(middlewares))
);

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);

export default store;
```

In order to successfully implement `redux-observable`, we have to obey this order:

1. Creating epicMiddleware using `createEpicMiddleware()` method
2. Using the `applyMiddleware()` method to register the epicMiddleware (the `redux-devtools-extension` is optional)
3. Calling the `epicMiddleware.run()` with the `rootEpic` we created earlier.

This is the instruction from the Redux-Observable Document

[image]

For more information, you could find it here: : [Setting Up The Middleware](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/SettingUpTheMiddleware.html):

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, have you tried:

```
import { epicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'
const epicMiddleware = epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic)
```

?

Comment: tried got error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined`