# TypeError: action$.ofType(...).mergeMap is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-observable

I am new to reactjs and trying to integrate redux with my existing project.

This is my **`index.js`** file in store

```
import 'rxjs'
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable'

import user, { userEpic } from './user/duck'
import app from './app'

// Bundling Epics
const rootEpic = combineEpics(
    userEpic
)

// Creating Bundled Epic
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)

// Define Middleware
const middleware = [
  thunk,
  promise(),
  epicMiddleware
]

// Define Reducers
const reducers = combineReducers({
  app,
  user,
  form: formReducer
})

// Create Store
export default createStore(reducers,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(), applyMiddleware(...middleware))
```

And here is **`duck.js`**

```
const createUserEpic = (action$) =>
  action$
  .ofType(SIGNUP_CONCIERGE)
  .mergeMap((action) => {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(api.signUpConcierge(action.payload))
    .flatMap((payload) => ([{
      type: SIGNUP_CONCIERGE_SUCCESS,
      payload
    }]))
    .catch((error) => Rx.Observable.of({
      type: SIGNUP_CONCIERGE_ERROR,
      payload: { error }
    }))
  })

export const userEpic = combineEpics(
  createUserEpic
)
```

which throws me error `TypeError: action$.ofType(...).mergeMap is not a function`

I have been getting this error since I updated react, react-redux, redux-observable versions.

What I am doing wrong here? Please help!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

First, import these functions at the very top of your file

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
```

Then, fix your codes like this (notice that, `ofType()` and `mergeMap()` is seperated by a `comma`, not a `dot`) :

```
const createUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(  //fixed
    ofType(SIGNUP_CONCIERGE),
    mergeMap(action => {
      return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(api.signUpConcierge(action.payload))
        .flatMap(payload => [
          {
            type: SIGNUP_CONCIERGE_SUCCESS,
            payload
          }
        ])
        .catch(error =>
          Rx.Observable.of({
            type: SIGNUP_CONCIERGE_ERROR,
            payload: { error }
          })
        );
    })
  );

export const userEpic = combineEpics(createUserEpic);
```

You forgot the `pipe()` method and also importing `ofType` and `mergeMap` methods from the appropriate packages.

After importing those methods, in order to use them, you first need to use the `pipe()` method like this:

```
 action$.pipe();
```

After that, you'll be able to use the `ofType()` and `mergeMap()` methods:

```
 action$.pipe(
     ofType(),
     mergeMap()
 );
```

Notice that they are separated by `comma`, not `dot`.

Comment: Still I didn't get you. From where `ofType()` comes from?

Comment: Thanks buddy you are awesome. I have one more problem but for that I will surely ask a new question. Thank you

Comment: Can you please look it to that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222160/uncaught-typeerror-providing-your-root-epic-to-createepicmiddlewarerootepic

Comment: @DarkKnight I've provided a complete answer with example and document.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/78), every `rxjs` operator should be included before you use it.

And people suggest that whether you `import rxjs` on your `index.js` file (not a `store/index.js` but your project entry file).

or you can do `import rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap` in your `duck.js`.

Either way works and it's up to you which way to choose.